# How to return different values ​of min, avg and max in e_mark_point?

Tags: r, echarts4r

I have this data:

```
library(echarts4r)

x <- c(10, 20, 30, 45, 46, 50)
y <- c(12, 25, 36, 46, 49, 59)

matrixinc1 <- data.frame(x, y)

near_line <- function(matriz) {
  diferenca <- abs(matriz[, 1] - matriz[, 2])
  indice <- which.min(diferenca)
  return(matriz[indice, , drop = FALSE])
}

near <- near_line(matrixinc1)
near

matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point(data = near)
```

I tried to make the x value represented by 45 and the y value be represented by 46. But I couldn't make this adjustment in the graph. Is it possible to do this so that the markers are not on top of each other?

I tried this too:

```
matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point("x", data = near[,1]) |> 
  e_mark_point("y", data = near[,2])
```

And this:

```
 matrixinc1[["test"]] <- near$x

avg <- list(
  type = "value",
  value = near$x,  # Atribui o valor de near[,1] à propriedade 'value'
  name = "AVG"
)

matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point("x", data = avg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to place markers at specific points you could do so by setting the `coord` attribute which should be a vector containing the x and the y coordinate. To this end I refactored you function to return the required vector.

```
library(echarts4r)

x <- c(10, 20, 30, 45, 46, 50)
y <- c(12, 25, 36, 46, 49, 59)

matrixinc1 <- data.frame(x, y)

near_line <- function(matriz, cols = c("x", "y")) {
  diferenca <- abs(matriz[, 1] - matriz[, 2])
  indice <- which.min(diferenca)

  unname(
    unlist(
      matriz[indice, cols, drop = TRUE]
    )
  )
}

near_y <- list(
  coord = near_line(matrixinc1),
  value = "y"
)

near_x <- list(
  coord = near_line(matrixinc1, c("x", "x")),
  value = "x"
)

matrixinc1 |>
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_line(x) |>
  e_line(y) |>
  e_mark_point(serie = "y", data = near_y) |>
  e_mark_point(
    serie = "x", data = near_x, symbolRotate = 180,
    label = list(verticalAlign = "top")
  )
```

[image]